# CodeIgniter Create and Update to table

Tags: php, codeigniter

right to the problem, anyone please help me...

1. I have an array

   Controller :

   ```
   $choosen_vendor = $_POST ['choosen_vendor'];
   print_r($choosen_vendor); echo "<br/>";
   <br/> Array ( [0] => Flash Computer [1] => Toko Jameson's [2] => Flash   Computer [3] => Donaldson Filtration Indonesia [4] => Donaldson Filtration Indonesia [5] => )
   ```
2. Next I've do something like this (will be used to update a table)

   - create number of data as number of $choosen_vendor, but if an array have same value, it'll be count as one => IT WORKED
   - add and auto increment ata tje end of ref_no as id_po of it => IT WORKED

     Controller :

     ```
     $numven = count(array_count_values(array_filter($choosen_vendor)));
     $ar = array_filter(array_unique($choosen_vendor));
     $povendor = array_values($ar);

     $R = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_max_po ();
     $maxpo = $R [0] -> po_id + 1;
     $beref = $_POST ['beref'];

     for ($i=0; $i < $numven; $i++) {
     $update = array (
         'pr_id' => $_POST ['prid'] [$i],
         'rfq_id' => $_POST ['rfq_id'] [$i],
         'vendor_name' => $povendor [$i] ,
         'pr_ref_no' => $_POST ['pr_ref'],
         'ref_no' => $beref.$maxpo++ ,
         'status' => $_POST ['statuspo'] ,
         'status_date' => $_POST ['status_date'] ,
         );
     //$this -> model_prcsys -> create_po ($update);
     print_r($update); echo "<br/>";
     }
     Array ( [pr_id] => 1 [rfq_id] => 1 [vendor_name] => Flash Computer    [pr_ref_no] => PR/AI/15/08/1 [ref_no] => PO/SA/15/09/1 [status] => REQ for PO  [status_date] => 2015/09/14 )
     Array ( [pr_id] => 1 [rfq_id] => 1 [vendor_name] => Toko Jameson's   [pr_ref_no] => PR/AI/15/08/1 [ref_no] => PO/SA/15/09/2 [status] => REQ for PO  [status_date] => 2015/09/14 )
     Array ( [pr_id] => 1 [rfq_id] => 1 [vendor_name] => Donaldson Filtration Indonesia [pr_ref_no] => PR/AI/15/08/1 [ref_no] => PO/SA/15/09/3 [status] => REQ for PO [status_date] => 2015/09/14 )
     ```
3. I'll update the item table as it `$_POST`, but if `$def_price` or `$vendor` is empty (0.00), ignore it (get result from view).
   On my view is like this :

   ```
     if ( ($def_price != '0.00') || ($vendor != '') )
   { ?> <input type="hidden" name="prlineid[]" value="<?php echo $row -> pr_line_id ?>" /> <?php }
   ```

   else { ?>

   ```
       $code = $_POST ['prlineid'];
   $count = count($code);
   for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   $update2 = array (
          'status' => $_POST ['statusline'] [$i],
          'log_date' => $_POST ['log_date'],
           );
   $idline = $code [$i];
   //$this -> model_prcsys -> update_linesas_reqforpo ($update,$idline);
   print_r($idline); echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   print_r($update2); echo "<br/>";
   }
   ```

```
1   Array ( [status] => REQ for PO [log_date] => Array ( [0] => 2015/09/14 [1] => 2015/09/14 [2] => 2015/09/14 [3] => 2015/09/14 [4] => 2015/09/14 [5] => 2015/09/14 ) )
<br/>
2   Array ( [status] => REQ for PO [log_date] => Array ( [0] => 2015/09/14 [1] => 2015/09/14 [2] => 2015/09/14 [3] => 2015/09/14 [4] => 2015/09/14 [5] => 2015/09/14 ) )
<br/>
4   Array ( [status] => REQ for PO [log_date] => Array ( [0] => 2015/09/14 [1] => 2015/09/14 [2] => 2015/09/14 [3] => 2015/09/14 [4] => 2015/09/14 [5] => 2015/09/14 ) )
<br/>
6   Array ( [status] => REQ for PO [log_date] => Array ( [0] => 2015/09/14 [1] => 2015/09/14 [2] => 2015/09/14 [3] => 2015/09/14 [4] => 2015/09/14 [5] => 2015/09/14 ) )
<br/>
7   Array ( [status] => REQ for PO [log_date] => Array ( [0] => 2015/09/14 [1] => 2015/09/14 [2] => 2015/09/14 [3] => 2015/09/14 [4] => 2015/09/14 [5] => 2015/09/14 ) )
//IT WORKED, it means it'll update as line_id and ignored the empty cause it not $_POST-ed
```

My Problem is : in $update2, I need POST PO_ID that have been created on my no.2 function to of each line_id that create it, or in other word, i need to have this :

- id 1 will get PO_ID 1 (from vendor Flash)
- id 2 will get PO_ID 2 (from vendor Jameson)
- id 4 will get PO_ID 1 (from vendor Flash)
- id 6 will get PO_ID 3 (from vendor Donalson)
  id 7 will get PO_ID 3 (from vendor Donalson)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to say, explain or even ask.
Could you please be more explaing, using more words is not a bad thing, i dont care if your english is bad just tell us more what it is for etc.explain what your controller does, explain what you got but what you expected to get

Comment: i hope someone can face to face to me right now ... i'm really bad on explaining thing ...